# Display an image when the web server is accessed

Tags: apache-http-server, php, webserver, html, minecraft

I run a Minecraft network on a dedicated debian 8 jessie machine and I have a LAMP server running on it.

I want to know how can I make it so when people put my server IP into their browser and hit enter they don't see the directories but instead it displays a image. Also if I want to access, for example, something I would usually just click on I would be able to do server IP/control panel and it would load it like it normally would.

Comment: create a webpage to host on the server, which links the image in an IMG tag. Then configure apache to display the webpage as its default document.

Answer (score 0):

Although the precise details could vary based on configuration, the following instructions represent a way that works with the most typical configurations.

- Make a filenamed index.html
- Place the following contents in that file:

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Picture</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><IMG SRC="file.png"></BODY></HTML>

The contents between the quotation marks is a filename.  Adjust as desired.

(These instructions are intentionally incomplete, for simplicity.  They assume you're already familiar with how to edit a text file, transfer files if needed, and set permissions if needed (so that the desired resulting file is readable to the world).  Since the question sounds like graphics were probably visible, these instructions are assuming no problem with any of those steps.)

Comment: thanks i got to that part atm i need more help with setting it as my default page and how to maybe add some css i want something that doesnt look that plain like this for example http://testplugins.com

Comment: i currently have the html file done and the htaccess file made i just dont know how to create a home.php file that runs the html file i need it to run

Comment: Fine.  But I did answer the initial question.  In fact, I have some further help that I thought of, that I could give.  However, the Stack Exchange format discourages (in an attempt to get closer to whatever you imagine) adding more and more questions being added to a single official "question" page.  If you seek more adjustments, make more changes between the <BODY> and </BODY> tags.  If you need more details about how to make further desired adjustments, then mark this answer as having answered the initial question, and then ask more questions, maybe at [webmasters.stackexchange.com].